# phpmailer with hotmail?

Tags: php, phpmailer, hotmail

I'm trying to send emails from my server by a PHP script. I used to send it by a native php function mail and everything worked OK. Here's the code I used:

```
$to  = $sMail;<br>
$subject = $sSubject;<br>
$message = $sMessage;

$headers  = 'From: user@domain.com' . "\r\n";<br>
$headers .= 'Reply-To: user@domain.com' . "\r\n";<br>
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";<br>
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";<br>


$bRes = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I then switched to PHPMailer, and wasn't able to send mail to Hotmail accounts (all the other still worked). Hotmail server reports the error: "550 SC-001 Mail rejected by Windows Live Hotmail for policy reasons."

This is the code I used for PHPMailer:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();<br>
$mail->IsHTML(true);<br>
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';<br>
$mail->From     = 'user@domain.com';<br>
$mail->FromName = 'domain.com';<br>
$mail->Subject  = $sSubject;;<br>
$mail->Body     = $sMessage;<br>
$mail->AltBody  = strip_tags($sMessage;);<br>
$mail->AddAddress($sMail);<br>
$mail->Send();<br>
$mail->ClearAddresses();<br>
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

As the sending works with the native function, I'm sure my server is able to send mails to hotmail. There must be a property to set when using PHPMailer, but I can't seem to find the right one. Anyone knows something abouth this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried sending just one e-mail to a hotmail account? If its multiple e-mails being sent, hotmail might suspect its spam and block it

Comment: Yes, I'm only trying to send one email each time.

Comment: maby you try to attach an exe file?

Comment: No, no attachment at all. It's an email that I use just for testing for the moment and it contains one sentence only. I guess that there's something in the header??

Comment: add a reply to address and that will fix it

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete line `$mail->FromName = 'domain.com';`

Comment: I tried that, but no change. If it helps, here's the message body that's included in the error response:

Comment: Return-Path: <xxx@xxxxxx.xxx> 
Received: (qmail 28894 invoked by uid 33); 23 Jan 2010 15:15:21 
-0600 
To: xxx@hotmail.com 
Subject: Subject 
Date: Sat, 23 Jan 2010 15:15:21 -0600 
From: Root User <xxx@xxxxxx.xxx> 
Message-ID: <---@xxxxxx.xxx> 
X-Priority: 3 
X-Mailer: PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.0 rc3] MIME-Version: 1.0 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="xxx" 
--xxx 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "UTF-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 

Body 

--xxx